# Llamar función PHP desde línea de comandos Yii

Tags: php, linux, yii

Quería ejecutar una función de PHP por línea de comandos en Linux y no me funciona, me sale siempre este error:

> PHP ParseError: syntax error, unexpected end of File in Command Line on Line 1

El código que escribe es éste:

```
php -r "require '/var/www/html/Proyecto/proyecto/protected/modules/cliente/controllers/ClienteController.php'; actionGenerarInformes();"
```

PD: Estoy usando el framework Yii.

Comment: La orden parece correctamente formada, pero parece que estás tratando de llamar a un controlador sin pasar por el framework. Sin saber el contenido del controlador no podremos saber qué te falta para hacerlo funcionar fuera de él (como los parámetros que se requieren para su ejecución, carga de dependencias, etc).

Comment: Es muy raro que quieras llamar a un `actionAltaCliente()` (acción de alta de datos de un cliente) sin entregar ningún tipo de dato sobre el nuevo alta (por poner un ejemplo).

Comment: No, no le pasan ningún parámetro. El proyecto es un ejemplo, al igual que la función. Lo siento por la confusión.

Comment: Estás usando la versión 2.0, ¿verdad?.

Comment: Estoy usando la 1.1.13 de Yii

Comment: Ok, entonces la forma de importar un controlador cambia un poco. Un momento busco en la documentación y te digo cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias! Es que llevo intentándolo un buen rato y de mil maneras diferentes y nada...

Comment: Es que debes pensar que lo que piensas que es una función, en realidad es un método de una clase. Primero debes instanciar la clase y posteriormente debes llamarla. Prueba la solución que te he puesto haciendo uso de `import`, aunque es probable que también te funcione sin pasar por el framework, todo depende de tu implementación y las dependencias que uses de él.

Comment: Ojo, acabo de hacer una modificación importante en la que he cambiado las comillas dobles por sencillas para evitar que `$controlador` se interprete como variable de entorno en vez de variable de PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Haciendo uso de `yiic`

Es más mucho más fácil de mantener y ejecutar comandos a través de la herramienta [`yiic`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/es/topics.console).

Puedes crear una clase que extienda a [`CConsoleCommand`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CConsoleCommand) en el directorio `protected/commands`.

Si sólo vas a implementar una única acción entonces necesitas implementar el método [`CConsoleCommand::run()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CConsoleCommand#run-detail) de la siguiente manera:

**PruebaCommand.php**

```
class PruebaCommand extends CConsoleCommand
{
    public function run($args) {
        Yii::import('application.modules.cliente.controllers.ClienteController');
        $controlador = new ClienteController('Pruebas');
        $controlador->actionGenerarInformes();
    }
}
```

Para probar su funcionamiento basta con ejecutar la siguiente instrucción desde el directorio `protected`:

```
./yiic prueba
```

En caso de no existir los ejecutables para Linux `yiic` y Windows `yiic.bat` se puede ejecutar de manera alternativa de la siguiente manera:

```
php yiic.php prueba
```

### Sin hacer uso de `yiic`

Asumiendo que tu código no funcionaría sin las dependencias del framework, debes cargarlo previamente con un `require 'ruta_al_archivo/yii.php'` y posteriormente debes importar tu controlador haciendo uso de [Yii::import()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#import-detail).

Tras la importación podrás ser capaz de instanciar el controlador y llamar a uno de sus métodos de la siguiente manera:

```
php -r '
  require "ruta_a/yii.php";
  Yii::import("application.modules.cliente.controllers.ClienteController");
  $controlador = new ClienteController("Pruebas");
  $controlador->actionGenerarInformes();
'
```

Para ahorrarte rutas largas es mejor posicionarse en el raíz del proyecto previamente con un `cd <ruta>` y agregar rutas relativas en el `require`.

PD: He cambiado el uso de comillas dobles por comillas simples en la instrucción `php -r '...'` para evitar que la shell interprete las variables de PHP como variables de entorno.

PD2: Para poder hacer uso de esta solución debes copiar el archivo de configuración de tu entorno a `console.php`.

Comment: Me sale este error, no sé que tiene que ver: `PHP FATAL ERROR: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/Proyecto/proyecto/protected/config/console.php ` (include_path=' .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/Proyecto/yii-1.1.13/framework/base/CApplication.php on line 133

Comment: Copia el archivo de configuración a `console.php` por si con eso te basta.

Comment: A qué te refieres? A que copie el main.php?

Comment: En la [documentación aparece esto](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console#customizing-console-applications) acerca de la ejecución desde línea de comandos (haciendo uso de `yiic`). Voy a echarle un vistazo para ver si se puede simplificar tu tarea con esa herramienta.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81247/discussion-on-answer-by-oscargarcia-llamar-funcion-php-desde-linea-de-comandos-y).